Uniform Convergence of Orthogonal Polynomials Under Weak Convergence of Measures
I'm currently studying orthogonal polynomials and a question came up that I couldn't find an answer to directly or corresponding literature.
Let $\mu$ be a distribution on $[a,b]$ with associated orthogonal polynomials $(p_j)_{j = 0}^n$.
Suppose I have a weakly convergent sequence of distributions $\mu^k \rightharpoonup \mu$ where $\text{supp}(\mu^k) \subset [a,b]$.
Is there a sequence of orthogonal polynomials $(p_j^k)_{j = 0}^n$ with respect to $\mu^k$, such that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{k \to \infty}\|p_j^k - p_j \|_\infty = 0 \quad \text{ for } j = 0,...,n \text{ ?}
\end{align*}
In particular, I had also asked myself whether it is possible to deduce the existence of such a sequence directly from the Gram-Schmidt method if $(p_j)_{j = 0}^n$ and $(p_j^k)_{j = 0}^n$ were both constructed using this method, as we have given the convergence of the moments through the compact support.
I appreciate any kind of help or literature recommendation.

I don’t wan’t to give you false hope but I think I did an exam on this particular problem, unfortunately I don’t remember when. Based on my memory the result is true but I can’t say more. Although I’m not sure about the type of convergence that was used
